# Dorot professor?

Tags: terminology

I encountered the term in a passage from an article in BBC History Magazine:

> In her book Denying the Holocaust: The Growing Assault on Truth and
>   Memory, published in the UK in 1994, Lipstadt (now the **Dorot professor**
>   of modern Jewish and Holocaust studies at Emory University in the US)
>   had called Irving a Holocaust denier and a falsifier of history.

I've searched a bit, finding that a few others have this title. but couldn't find the meaning of it. I kind of have a feeling that it is something to do with her being a Jew after I compared the English and Chinese versions of her entry on Wikipedia, but can't be sure. Anyone knows what it is? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "The {x} professor" is quite a common construction in academia, where {x} sponsors the position. This is therefore not a language question.

Comment: I think how to understand a modifier before the title Professor is a language question, whether such construction is common or not.  But the question's been fully, totally, answered; we're done. Perhaps the issue is how to title it so that others who have the same generic question will find it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is based on a typo in the quote the OP is asking about: it should be the Dorot Professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching for something tangible, item 10 at: https://www.hdot.org/ws-dlipstadt/ quotes Lipstadt's witness statement:

> "Shortly after my arrival at Emory, the University submitted a proposal to the Dorot Foundation, a major foundation which has endowed a number of positions at various universities throughout the United States. The proposal suggested a number of different ways the foundation might support Emory. The Foundation selected the most “costly ” of these proposals and elected to endow a chair. They made a gift to the university of 1.25 million dollars. The President of the Foundation, the late Joy Ungerleider Mayerson, informed the university that it chose the option of the chair because I would be the occupant. In recognition of my areas of expertise, the Foundation named the chair the Dorot Chair in Modern Jewish and Holocaust Studies."

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon due to link-rot, and may be removed. Please quote the relevant sentences (with textual attribution/citation as well).

Comment: @JonMark How absolutely cool.  Could we combine our answers--the specific and the general?

Comment: @JonMark  I added the quotation; it will show up when peer reviewed.

Answer (score 5):

It is likely that the Dorot Foundation has endowed her position at Emory.  Endowing a professorship (often then called a "named chair"), is a common way to contribute to a university.  See "https://www.dorot.org/  Dorot Foundation: Charitable family foundation. Includes information about grants for student travel to Israel and other purposes." I would assume that the Dorot Foundation likes her work and wants to support it.  See other answer for confirmation. When you see a faculty member identified, e.g., as "The John and Mary Smith Professor of XXX," it's likely a chair endowed by the Smiths.